# Android Database - behaving weird?

Tags: android

I want to have a search between specific dates. Say for example from the 1st of Aug 2012 to 13th Aug 2012. Search on this criteria gives me the entered value in the DB. If I make it 2nd Aug 2012, the query returns me null...Even weirder is that when I select 10th, 11th or the 12th Dates it works fine and gives me results...I have gone crazy trying to know where the issue could be and debug has not lead me any where....Help please?

```
/**query to get the details by giving all the dates/
public Cursor getName_Intime_Outtime_Date(String fromdate,String todate)
   {
    Log.d("pavan","in side the getnameintime out time date() of visistor adapter");
   return this.db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_VISITOR,
      new String[]{KEY_NAME,KEY_CHECKIN,KEY_CHECKOUT,KEY_DATE},
      KEY_DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?", 
      new String[] {fromdate ,todate}, 
      null, null, null, null);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite doesn't have a data type for dates. Probably you save your date as TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
I recommend you save date fields in your table as sqlLite datatype `INTEGER` as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, or as `BIGINT` (long java time version in miliseconds).

This way you would have a corect value returned when using `BETWEEN` with numbers.

**EDIT**
You can manage your date string from your query using [date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). This means you can still use your dates as strings, but performing casts to "DATE" using conversion functions when stringDates are used in sql WHERE clause.

Comment: Yes I store it as strings...will try your suggestion and keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

try this, it is working for me, SELECT * FROM table_name
where substr(column_name,7)||substr(column_name,4,2)||substr(column_name,1,2) 
      between 'YYMMDD' and 'YYMMDD' , dates should be in reverse order eg: if date format is DD/MM/YY or DD-MM-YY , you can use 'YYMMDD'

Comment: Thanks Madhavi...will try and let u know

Comment: can I know the date type, i mean is it DATETIME or String?

Comment: giving datatype as DATETIME works for Jan to July, does not work for Aug with dates between 2 - 9, works again for Sep to Dec...Dont know what is wrong.....this is really weird

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for really looking into this...Finally solved this using idea found in this link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/Ey_4rBZx2t0%5B1-25%5D ....to summarize what I did was take a Calendar object, retrieve the current date using the Calendar object, the retrieved data is given to a simpledateformat object and comparisons to be made on that....Here is the sample code...

```
int test = date_pick.getMonth()+1;
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Date seleted month"+test+"/"+date_pick.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+date_pick.getYear(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, date_pick.getYear());
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, test);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date_pick.getDayOfMonth());

       /* retriving the yyyy mm dd values here*/
         set_year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         set_month= cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         set_day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
         Log.d("kunal","datesis "+set_year+" "+set_month+" "+set_day);
         string_date = set_year+"-"+set_month+"-"+set_day;


     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
     try {
       d1 = sdf.parse(string_date);
      Log.d("kunal","date came "+d1);
      System.out.println(sdf.format(d1));      

     } catch (ParseException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
      date_txt.setText(sdf.format(d1));
```